# Google Script event undefined

Tags: events, google-apps-script

I've built a Google Script which runs when my Spreadsheet is edited:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  Browser.msgBox(event.source);
  general(event);
}
```

When my function is named onEdit(), the Browser.msgBox returns "Spreadsheet" (so the source is   defined)
When my function is named othername(), the Browser.msgBox retunrs "undefined".

I execute the script with the same user, the script runs when my Spreadsheet is edited and i don't change anything else than the name of the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`onEdit` is an event in [Google Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events), so changing it's name will generate different behavior.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

event.source stays undefined when you use another function than onEdit().

I've replaced event.source by event.range and now it works.

I don't understand why but it runs.

Comment: Events for various triggers are described in [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events). The `event` object varies depending on the nature of the event.